# How to terminate a child process when using exec()

Tags: unix, posix, fork

I understand when a forked child process is created, that process can be terminated by exit(), but when the child executes another program (execvp(), execlp(), etc..) any code written after that is ignored. At that point how does the child process terminate? How does it tell the parent it has ended?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The child process doesn't exit when you `exec`. What happens is - the current process is replaced by whatever it's `exec`ing.

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

So yes - any code after the `exec` is effectively discarded. Normally, what'll happen is a `fork` then an `exec` - creating a child process, with a new executable image, which you then wait for it to complete (or not) with something like `waitpid` (Which will block until child exit, and reap a return code).

When `fork`ing the *only* difference in your program states at that point, is the return code of the fork - which is the child pid. Which stays the same when your child calls `exec`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec

Comment: what code is waitpid expecting to indicate the child has ended?

Comment: Depends how you call it. By default - it'll block until the child exits and then return the exit status of the child.

Comment: On the other hand, the exec() functions could fail (for instance due to lack of resources).  In that case, the failed process should exit -- usually with _exit() -- http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit -- , to avoid interfering with the parent).